# Mypy error when checking stdlib functions?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, typechecking, python-typing

I have a routine to creaate a powerset that works. I added a few type annotations to arguments and the return value then ran Mypy on the result.

Mypy seems to have issues with stdlib functions, is this to be expected?

```py
(base) paddy3118@Paddy-G14:/mnt/c/Users/paddy/Google Drive/Code$ python -V
Python 3.8.5
(base) paddy3118@Paddy-G14:/mnt/c/Users/paddy/Google Drive/Code$ mypy -V
mypy 0.761
(base) paddy3118@Paddy-G14:/mnt/c/Users/paddy/Google Drive/Code$ uname -a
Linux Paddy-G14 4.19.128-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Tue Jun 23 12:58:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
(base) paddy3118@Paddy-G14:/mnt/c/Users/paddy/Google Drive/Code$ cat pwrset_mypy.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Mar 30 14:59:19 2021

@author: Paddy3118
"""
from itertools import chain, combinations
from typing import List, Tuple


def powerset(s: List[int]) -> List[Tuple[int]]:
    """powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3) ."""
    return list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert powerset([0, 1, 2]) == [(), (0,), (1,), (2,), (0, 1), (0, 2),
                                   (1, 2), (0, 1, 2)]
(base) paddy3118@Paddy-G14:/mnt/c/Users/paddy/Google Drive/Code$
(base) paddy3118@Paddy-G14:/mnt/c/Users/paddy/Google Drive/Code$ mypy  --show-error-context --show-column-numbers --show-error-codes --pretty pwrset_mypy.py
pwrset_mypy.py: note: In function "powerset":
pwrset_mypy.py:13:37: error: Generator has incompatible item type "Iterator[Tuple[int, ...]]"; expected
"Iterable[Tuple[int]]"  [misc]
        return list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1)))
                                        ^
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
(base) paddy3118@Paddy-G14:/mnt/c/Users/paddy/Google Drive/Code$
``
```

Comment: `Tuple[int]` means a tuple containing a *single* int.

Comment: How does one state that it returns a list of Tuples of zero or more ints, please?

Comment: it's right in the error message you got from mypy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an error because your type annotation is wrong.  The error message is telling you exactly how to fix it -- you can use `Tuple[int, ...]` instead of `Tuple[int]`.

```
def powerset(s: List[int]) -> List[Tuple[int, ...]]:
    """powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3) ."""
    return list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1)))
```

Unless it's important for the caller to know that these are tuples specifically, another option would be to specify them as `Iterable[int]`s:

```
def powerset(s: List[int]) -> List[Iterable[int]]:
    """powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3) ."""
    return list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1)))
```

Note that a `Tuple[int]` is specifically a tuple containing a single `int`, whereas an `Iterable[int]` is any iterable containing any number of `int`s.  Tuple type declarations take a type parameter for each position of the tuple -- because each individual tuple is immutable, it's possible to annotate each position and know that the typing will be preserved, so you can have for example a `Tuple[int, int]` or a `Tuple[int, str]`, etc.

Comment: Success! Thanks - I was thrown by the given location of the error.

Comment: I think it's pointing at that spot because that's where the value that disagrees with your return type originates from.  `chain.from_iterable` just returns the type of its input, so pointing at that as the source of the error would be unhelpful.  The `Tuple[int, ...]` return type that disagrees with your declared `Tuple[int]` return type is actually coming from `combinations`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Hopefully my understanding og Mypy errors will grow with use.

Comment: mypy mostly annoyed and confused me when I first started using it about four years ago, and now it's literally my favorite part of working with Python :D